# Time-out exception in SQL Server rarely

Tags: sql-server, timeoutexception

I have used SQL Server 2012 for my web application and I've got time-out exception rarely. Could you please advise this?

Stack trace details:

[image]

Thank in advance,

Subash Ravi

Answer (score 0):

there is no timeout on SQL Server, you should increment the timeout of your web application instead.

Maybe you can try to :

Increase the server website timeout :

```
<httpRuntime 
    maxRequestLength="1048576"
    executionTimeout="90"
/>
```

Check connection pool size and connect timeout :

```
conn.ConnectionString = "integrated security=SSPI;SERVER=YOUR_SERVER;DATABASE=YOUR_DB_NAME;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=60;Connect Timeout=60;"
```

Always do a close connection to be sure your pool is not full

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString);
     try
         {
              conn.Open();
             doSomething(conn);
        }
   finally
       {
         conn.Close();
         conn.Dispose();
      }
```